# Why does my for-loop not work properly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

New in Python, hope ya'll can help

I have a script with this for loop that checks a list of files from a directory and what I need to do is if each file ends with 'xlsx' it does a block of code, if it ends with 'csv' it does other block code.
I had to create the variable **extension** to extract the extension of the file because it showed an error WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith' if I used the **file**

```
for file in file_list:
        #to extract the file extension:
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1][1:]
        print(file)

        if extension.endswith('xlsx'):
            all_df_list.append(pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl'))
            a = round(time.time() - start_time,2)
            print(a)
        elif extension.endswith('csv'):
            all_df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=10000))
            a = round(time.time() - start_time,2)
            print(a)
        else:
            print("Not working")
```

When I run the whole script, it starts the loop and executes the command for the first file, but then it goes all the way down to else statement. It was supposed to do the same for each file... These are the results (put xxx to hide sensitive info)

```
Z:\DataFiles\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX_XXX_0000.xlsx
2.43
Z:\DataFiles\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX_XXX_2019.XLSX
Not working
Z:\DataFiles\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX_XXX_2020.XLSX
Not working
Z:\DataFiles\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX_XXX_2021.XLSX
Not working
Z:\DataFiles\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXXX_2022.XLSX
Not working
```

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `file_list` (or can you send the full code)?

Comment: "XLSX" does not, in fact, end with "xlsx".  You need to apply `.lower()` to `extension`, so you can compare it without caring about case.

Comment: Looks to me like you intend your extension check to be case insensitive, but haven't implemented that. Something like `extension = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()` ought to help.

Comment: `extension.lower().endswith('xlsx')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `file` is a `WindowsPath` object (as indicated by the error), you probably want to use [`.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix), and use `.lower()` to lowercase it before comparing against lowercase extensions:

```
for file in file_list:
    if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx':
        all_df_list.append(pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl'))
    elif file.suffix.lower() == '.csv':
        all_df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=10000))
    else:
        print("Not working")
        continue
    print(round(time.time() - start_time, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is looking for .xlsx and .csv and therefore .XLSX is treated in the else:
block.
You could use the function `.lower()` when you assign the value to the variable extension.

```
extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1][1:].lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried different solutions and as suggested, I just used:

```
        if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx':
            all_df_list.append(pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl'))
            a = round(time.time() - start_time,2)
            print(a)
        elif file.suffix.lower() == '.csv':
            all_df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=10000))
            a = round(time.time() - start_time,2)
            print(a)
```

and it worked. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you define `extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1][1:]` outside the loop?

Comment: `file` doesn't exist outside the loop, so this would just produce a `NameError` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pathlib` for pathing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and you can get the string from `.name`!

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path("foo/bar/baz.EXT")
>>> p.name.lower().endswith(".ext")
True
```

Comment: The OP is apparently already using `pathlib` without realizing it, based on the reference to the `WindowsPath` object. (Such objects already have a way to access the extension without parsing the full file name.)

Comment: oic - indeed, they just need the `.name` property then!